# Request should get response in 1sec in Microservice Architecture

Tags: java, microservices

Recently, I have faced one java interview question. It goes like this : "There are 3 Microservices (flow goes from 1st to 2nd to 3rd) which takes a minimum roundabout of 0.5sec to provide the response. But the web request should get response in 1sec itself. How to achieve this ?"

Any architecture design or pattern or any settings, need to do ?

Comment: you can start with, drawing three vertical lines name them `1st`, `2nd` and `3rd`, draw an arrow from each(1st to 2nd, 2nd to 3rd) and annotate it with the time taken. while doing this, ask yourself(or interviewer), what type of request is this, what is the response expected to be for each arrow you drew.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very vague question and there's no easy direct answer, it's more to identify in which direction you will go, what analisys options will you suggest. Its reliability engineering (SRE) which includes many tricks and approaches.

1. I would start by analyzing and clarifying what business process is   implemented by this requests sequence, think about needless (it happens that not always Developers write correct code, hence some non-needed calls to services, DB etc)
2. Monitor network latency and identify where is a focus area. If the network takes significant time, then makes sense to improve network hardware or software, look for problems, bad packages when the Client resends data, "Package storm" issue etc. If the network is fine, focus on services.
3. Then consider caching data from downstream services (In-progress cache or Distributed depends on architecture and data type). This step should be done carefully with a full understanding of data nature, e.g Can it be cached, for which period, which way to use for refreshing/evicting data?
4. Pay attention to the possibility of code optimisation which is executed. It happens, that Developers don't keep in mind performance during implementation, hence can create functionality with unneeded operations (for example some sorting, filtering, synchronization (with locks), etc).
5. Part of 3., parallelize everything that is possible inside the code execution (no guarantee it helps), get rid of locks. For example, there can be some dependencies on DB or other sources before/after calls to downstream service, which may lead to unpredicted blockings, in such a situation make sense to do execution of tasks in parallel threads without blocking each other.
6. If no low-level tricks help, it can ring a bell to revisit the architecture of services, e.g if SLO 1s is very important, then maybe it makes sense to join 1+2 or 2+3 microservices into bigger service to reduce data transformation and transferring between service (need to calc before).

There are much more things to consider, depends how deep you would like to go.

Comment: Seems, the answer to the question asked is more of a theoretical approach than practical. Thanks for the info.